# Do I need a special rack for my Schwinn Ascension hybrid bike with disk brakes?

Tags: brakes, wheels, rack, disc-brake, hybrid-bike

Do I need a special rear rack for my Schwinn Ascension Hybrid bike that has disc brakes? Or will the regular Schwinn bike rack work

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Charles. Just to be clear, do you mean the rack that attaches to the bike?

Comment: Yes I did Andy256.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about that bike that necessitates any special rear rack. You'll want to make sure that the bottom bolt that attaches on the disc side is not so long that it pokes the disc but that's true with any frame.